# UIScrollView and PanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I’m have a view that contains a regular UIView and a UIScrollView. The UIView sits above the UIScrollView offscreen. The UIScrollView typically occupies the entire screen. (It should be noted that I’m not using Autolayout). When the user scrolls to the top of the scrollview content I would like the UIView to start appearing on the screen. And when it reaches a certain threshold have the UIView snap into place and occupy the screen.

[image]

My initial thought was to use the  UIScrollView delegate method, and adjust the superview.frame.orgin.y value when the scrollview contentOffset.y value is negative.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    pullDownInProgress = scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.0

    if pullDownInProgress {
        self.view. = (-self.view.height / 2) - scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
}
```

However, this creates a stretching between the UIView and the UIScrollView due the scrollview bounce setting. If I turn off the bounce setting then the scrollview.contentOffset is never less then zero, therefore my superview frame is never adjusted.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the superview.frame, instead move the offscreen view down by its height so that it can appears and any bouncing effect for the scroll view might be hidden  by that view.Or you can even move both the scroll view and the offscreen view with the height of the offscreen view. It really depends whether your offscreen view is transparent or not